# Today's podcast mentions that a badge was awarded to a user today, but it wasn't awarded today

Tags: support, badges, podcast

Today's podcast, [Kidnapping an NFT](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/06/03/episode-448-kidnapping-an-nft/) (June 3, 2022), mentions that today's [Lifeboat](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8842/lifeboat) badge was awarded to user [munk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633094/munk), but they were actually awarded the badge on 25th May, 2022.

The most recent badge was awarded to Stephen Docy:

[image]

Was this a mistake, or am I missing something?

Comment: Podcast is not live stream, it's being recorded and edited, like a TV show, so in the time they recorded it, it was true. Maybe worth asking to add "Date of recording" somewhere so it won't be confusing in cases like this one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Educated guess: the podcast was recorded on May 25th. When [Matt made that statement](https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/kidnapping-an-nft/transcript), it was true.